# Enabling ACLs in Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: mount, fstab

Hi I have a book on Linux that says "if I want to mount the device represented by `/home` to use ACLs on files in `/home` I have to add `acl` to its options in `/etc/fstab` then the book gives me this command:

```
$ grep home /etc/fstab/
LABEL=/home /home   ext4   defaults,acl   1 2
```

---

I'm confused because in my fstab file there is this line of code:

```
UUID=aaab87g4-u3ty-8s9i-1r4t-8d6f8765hf98 /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
```

(* I just put random numbers in the UUID; I'm new to this and don't know if I should be putting out the real UUID in my fstab file)

---

So should I put either one of the following lines of code under the one that is already there?

```
LABEL=/home /home ext2 defaults,acl 1 2
```

or

```
LABEL=/home /home ext2 default,acl 0 2
```

Comment: Also, you shouldn't mount using an older version of ext unless you know for sure that you must. Both of those lines should have `ext4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs):

> As of Ubuntu 14.04 and for ext4, the above is not required as acl are already default:
>
> ```
> sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdaX |grep acl
> Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
> ```

So, neither, since you're using 14.04 and `ext4`.

However, if you absolutely must change the mount options:

1. There should be no space after the comma. It should be `defaults,acl`.
2. You should edit the existing entry (the one that's shown by the grep command).

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted! ;-)